# Am I considered to be Catholic?

Tags: catholicism, baptism, presbyterianism

I noticed with surprise the following in a previous question :

> Finally, each and every Catholic, as also the baptized of every non-Catholic church or denomination who enters into the fullness of the Catholic communion,

I was baptised (in the name of the Father and of the Son and of the Holy Spirit) at the age of five (I can vividly remember it to this day, sixty-three years later) by a Presbyterian minister of the Church of Scotland.

At the age of fifteen I left the C of S and, for only a short time, joined with the Scottish Baptist movement and was baptised as an adult.

I subsequently was dissatisfied with the state of religion in Scotland and I moved to England, at the age of eighteen, to be under the ministry and guidance of someone I perceived as a genuine Minister of Jesus Christ and I continued with him for twenty five years. He did not think it necessary to baptise me again and he accepted my baptism and received me into fellowship with his congregation.

I was married, now I am celibate. I no longer drink alcohol and I don't do drugs. I earn a living and I do not steal. I last told a lie (that I can remember) in 2011, of which I am ashamed, although it was not a matter of criminality. The last time I remember taking the name of God or the Lord in vain (as a curse or as an expletive) was when I was fourteen years old.

So, am I accepted as Catholic or would I have to do anything further to be accepted as a Christian among Catholic persons ?

Comment: I see that non-alcoholic communion wine is available, in case you were wondering.

Comment: Let us be specific. Catholic means universal. Do you mean Roman Catholic?

Comment: @Reluctant_Linux_User No. I was being very specific in saying 'Catholic'.

Comment: Nigel, when did you last receive communion in a Catholic church?  (And I wonder at your capitalization).

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Regarding capitalisation, I am using 'Catholic' to describe myself in the same way that I use 'Protestant' to describe myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Are you considered to be Catholic?**

The short answer is **no**.

> Finally, each and every Catholic, as also the baptized of every non-Catholic church or denomination **who enters into the fullness of the Catholic communion**, must retain his own rite wherever he is, must cherish it and observe it to the best of his ability, without prejudice to the right in special cases of persons, communities or areas, to have recourse to the Apostolic See, which, as the supreme judge of interchurch relations, will, acting itself or through other authorities, meet the needs of the occasion in an ecumenical spirit, by the issuance of opportune directives, decrees or rescripts. -  [Orientalium Ecclesiarum](http://www.vatican.va/archive/hist_councils/ii_vatican_council/documents/vat-ii_decree_19641121_orientalium-ecclesiarum_en.html)

According to the above statement you have not entered into full communion with the Catholic Church.

In order for that to happen several thing must happen first.

Validly baptized non-Catholics who desire to enter into full communion with the Catholic Church must complete an RCIA course which explains the basic beliefs professed in Catholicism, prior to making a **profession of faith in the Catholic Church**.

> The **Rite of Christian Initiation of Adults** (RCIA), or **Ordo Initiationis Christianae Adultorum**   (OICA) is a process developed by the Catholic Church for prospective converts to Catholicism who are above the age of infant baptism. Candidates are gradually introduced to aspects of Catholic beliefs and practices. The basic process applies to adults and older children, with younger children initiated through an adapted version sometimes incorrectly referred to as the Rite of Christian Initiation of Children (RCIC). - [Rite of Christian Initiation of Adults](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rite_of_Christian_Initiation_of_Adults)

Comment: +1 and accepted. Appreciated. Do I just have to do the RCIA course, that is to say, is it an intellectual understanding of the doctrines and practices - or do I have to acknowledge my own acceptance of every single detail without any differences ?

Comment: @NigelJ you need to make a profession of faith. An intellectual understanding of the church is not sufficient. You must accept it, and perform the necessary rites before the congregation. RCIA is not simply an educational course, it is a rite.

Comment: The original post also had a question about whether the Catholic Church considers Nigel Christian, and the answer to that is yes because he received a valid baptism.

Comment: @NigelJ My good friend, I was a catechist in RCIA for some years.  It's a process, not a check in the box. ;-) .  All that I can ask is that you take the plunge. Best wishes whatever your decision.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I consider myself to be catholic already. The problem is that some are not prepared to accept my faith in Christ and the life that I live, as being Christian. And they exclude me. Which says more about them than it does about me.

Comment: *Which says more about them than it does about me*. @Nigel   Nope.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast To exclude someone who expresses faith in Jesus Christ (as he is set out in the holy scriptures) and whose conduct cannot be blamed : is to act contrary to the Christ and to act contrary to the Body of Christ. 'Yep' to your 'Nope'.

Comment: @NigelJ You are on the outside looking in; that is the only explanation I can come up with for your very un-Christian statement there.  I was once on the outside looking in as well, and all I can say is: you have no idea.  Hence the Nope.  This message is delivered with love.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast You exclude me already. 'On the outside' of what ? The Body of Christ ? Or an earthly organisation ?

Comment: @NigelJ *You exclude me already* No, I do not, but you chose to set yourself outside by your own words, in two ways.   *and whose conduct cannot be blamed* Pride goeth before a fall.  You were the one who referred to "they" and "them".  *Which says more about them than it does about me*  also *And they exclude me*   Your words, not mine.  I do not have the eloquence necessary, but Scott Hahn might.  (And yes, I read your 60,000 word pdf.  An extraordinary meditation, and an extraordinary journey).

Comment: I think it's worth explaining a little more. There are three sacraments of initiation in the Catholic Church. Nigel has received the first one, baptism. If he enrolls in RCIA at his church, he will get to know more people in the parish, take some classes, and spend time talking about the decision to become a Catholic. If he chooses to, he can then receive the sacraments of Eucharist and confirmation, probably in a big celebration on the following Easter Vigil. These sacraments are sacred rites that confer graces according to Catholic understanding.